# What is the best way to merge two files together automatically without getting a conflict?

Tags: git, merge, diff, auto

I'm having two files containing two doc blocks. `file1` is generated and filled with user input, `file2` is another generated doc block without filled in fields. I want these two doc blocks to be merged and if there is a conflict it should choose `--theirs` automatically (since this is `file2` and is the newer version).

Examples:

`file1` contains (user already filled in some `TODO` parts):

```
/**
 * Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec quis sem ut
 * felis imperdiet elementum. Etiam eu consequat felis. Suspendisse ac lectus
 * vel lacus blandit sollicitudin at ac sapien. Donec scelerisque nisl id tellus
 * faucibus tempor. Praesent accumsan turpis nisi.
 *
 * @param array $p1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
 * Duis gravida nisi eget mollis semper. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora.
 * @param float $p2 Lorem ipsum dor sit amet.
 * @param string $p3 (optional) Lorem ipsum dor sit amet.
 * @param \Drupal\core\Entity\Node $p4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
 * adipiscing elit. Mauris pharetra commodo dolor.
 * @return mixed [TODO:description]
 */
```

`file2` contains (newly generated doc block that has some changes):

```
/**
 * [TODO:description]
 *
 * @param array $myVar [TODO:description]
 * @param float $p2 [TODO:description]
 * @param [TODO:type] $p3 (optional) [TODO:description]
 * @param \Drupal\core\Entity\Node $p4 [TODO:description]
 * @param [TODO:type] $p5 [TODO:description]
 * @return [TODO:type] [TODO:description]
 */
```

I prefer to let git do the merging since its merging system and history merge algorithm is good, yet when I try to run: `$ git merge-file -p file1 file3 file2` (where `file3` is just empty) I'm getting the following output printed:

```
<<<<<<< file1
/**
 * Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec quis sem ut
 * felis imperdiet elementum. Etiam eu consequat felis. Suspendisse ac lectus
 * vel lacus blandit sollicitudin at ac sapien. Donec scelerisque nisl id tellus
 * faucibus tempor. Praesent accumsan turpis nisi.
 *
 * @param array $p1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
 * Duis gravida nisi eget mollis semper. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora.
 * @param float $p2 Lorem ipsum dor sit amet.
 * @param string $p3 (optional) Lorem ipsum dor sit amet.
 * @param \Drupal\core\Entity\Node $p4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
 * adipiscing elit. Mauris pharetra commodo dolor.
 * @return mixed [TODO:description]
 */
||||||| file3
=======
/**
 * [TODO:description]
 *
 * @param array $myVar [TODO:description]
 * @param float $p2 [TODO:description]
 * @param [TODO:type] $p3 (optional) [TODO:description]
 * @param \Drupal\core\Entity\Node $p4 [TODO:description]
 * @param [TODO:type] $p5 [TODO:description]
 * @return [TODO:type] [TODO:description]
 */
>>>>>>> file2
```

Perhaps this might have to do that `file3` is empty?

I expect the output to be the following:

```
/**
 * Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec quis sem ut
 * felis imperdiet elementum. Etiam eu consequat felis. Suspendisse ac lectus
 * vel lacus blandit sollicitudin at ac sapien. Donec scelerisque nisl id tellus
 * faucibus tempor. Praesent accumsan turpis nisi.
 *
 * @param array $myVar Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
 * Duis gravida nisi eget mollis semper. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora.
 * @param float $p2 Lorem ipsum dor sit amet.
 * @param string $p3 (optional) Lorem ipsum dor sit amet.
 * @param \Drupal\core\Entity\Node $p4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
 * adipiscing elit. Mauris pharetra commodo dolor.
 * @param [TODO:type] $p5 [TODO:description]
 * @return mixed [TODO:description]
 */
```

Comment: Git really needs the 3th file for its merging, it uses it to convert both file into "change sets", and then uses those to solve some of the conflicts. `file3` should have the contents of the file before the user started editing

Comment: @Ferrybig File 3 would be like this then: http://ix.io/1REm and if I run the same git command I receive this output: http://ix.io/1REo

Comment: You're asking for a merge algorithm that matches partial lines: Git's merge doesn't do that, it works over whole lines. For example, it cannot tell that `* @param float $p2 Lorem ipsum...` and `* @param float $p2 [TODO...` are the same line, modified. It would if the text on the surrounding lines was fixed, and it could if there was a `-w` variant to `git merge-file` like there is to `git diff`, but there isn't.